# Get Email ID Format from string?

Tags: c#

I have string where I have lot of email id in it.

I want get that email id from string using email format.
like blankspace before @ and Blankspace After @.

```
suppose i have string like this then how can i do this?

"Yunnan Coffee with the scientific name-Coffee test@example.com Arabica L was the variation of Arabia Coffee."
```

Then How can i get that Email id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You could use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method:</strike>

```
string email = "test@example.com";
string[] tokens = email.Split('@');
string enailId = tokens[0];
string domain = tokens[1];
```

---

UPDATE:

After your clarification here's how you could parse the email using a regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.Compiled);    
var s = "Yunnan Coffee with the scientific name-Coffee test@example.com Arabica L was the variation of Arabia Coffee.";
foreach (Match email in regex.Matches(s))
{
    Console.WriteLine(email.Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks

But suppose i have string like this then how can i do this?

"Yunnan Coffee with the scientific name-Coffee test@example.com Arabica L was the variation of Arabia Coffee."

Then How can i get that Email id?

Comment: Hello

Its worked for last string but not for this

<img src="http://www.chinacoopcoffee.com.cn/en/Images/zhongguo.jpg" width="26" height="14" />&nbsp;<a class="aBrown" href="../../DefaultHome.aspx">中文版</a></samp><samp style="margin:30px 20px 0px 0px; display:block; float:right; height:102px; width:380px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Add：No.14 Zhengjiao Road,Kunming,Yunnan 650223.P.R.China <br />

Email：coopcoffee@163.net<br />
Fox：+86(871)-5195599<br />
Tel：+86(871)5122496<br />
Tel2：+86(871)5199410<br />
</samp></div>

"

Please tell me how it work for this